# Why is my German visa appeal taking too much time at the Bengaluru consulate?

Tags: visa-refusals, visa-refusal-appeal

My German healthcare visa was rejected due to some accommodation issue. The rejection letter says *you have not enough money to pay for your accommodation.* But my employer gave it to me at a very low cost. After my rejection I sent an appeal on 8th November 2023 to the Bangalore consulate (India). It's been almost 10 weeks but there were no updates. My employer can only keep my position until this month. What should I do?

Comment: I doubt there is anything you can do here but others may know better.

Comment: Appeals are slow. They need to review the original application and decide if somebody was at fault. It is almost always faster to file a new application with the information corrected.

Comment: Can you write more about your situation? What do you mean "My employer can only keep my position until this month." Are you unable to work because of this medical issue? Who is paying for the actual medical care in Germany? It seems odd that your employer is willing to give you cheap accommodation, but unwilling to keep you employed while you are sick. What did you write on the application about the cost of accommodation? Please answer these by editing the question.